# How to sort ldap result after query

Tags: php, sorting, ldap

i have a code where i want to sort ldap results by sn. But it's not working.
What i am doing wrong? 
Thanks!

```
$att = array("company","samaccountname","ou","name","displayname", "sn", "givenname", "mail", "telephonenumber", "mobile","title","department");
$result=ldap_search($ldap_connection, $searchdn, $filter, $att);

$info = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);

ksort($info['sn']);

for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++)....
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [uasort](https://php.net/uasort) for that like this:

```
uasort($info, function($a, $b) {
    return strnatcasecmp($a['sn'], $b['sn']);
}) ;
```

(not tested but should work)

Using `ldap_sort` is deprecated as the underlying C-Function is deprecated for some years now and the sorting algorithm is also not flexible. With this approach you get the same functionality but with much more flexibility. And as both only sort the returned resultset you are better off using that approach.

Comment: Would it be possible to attach the ASN1 code for sorting to the request as well? So you would do server side sorting: https://github.com/FreeDSx/LDAP/blob/dcde4f49966d5d66f0076e3c89535cdd2684665c/src/FreeDSx/Ldap/Control/Sorting/SortingControl.php#L137-L142

Comment: You would need to do proper server side sorting which is possible since PHP7.4. See https://www.php.net/manual/de/ldap.controls.php for more infos.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's client side ldap sort function:

```
// Search
$results = ldap_search($ldap_connection, $searchdn, $filter, $att);

// Sort -- attribute on which to sort needs to be included in $att array
ldap_sort($ldap_connection, $result, 'sn');

// Get data
$info = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);
```

Comment: Thank you! I reading that ldap_sort has been DEPRECATED but it working for me!

Comment: ldap_sort is deprecated! You should not use that function anymore! Instead I'd use uasort or any other of the sorting-functions that use user-provided sorting algorithms. Have a look at https://php.net/uasort or https://php.net/uksort - and at https://php.net/ldap_sort